# How to brew install package into Enthought Canopy?

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew, enthought

I'm on OS X Mavericks and I'm using Enthought Canopy for my preferred Python distribution.

I have made the Canopy distribution my default Python, I have the line VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 at my .bash_profile and it is the one which starts when I type python.

So now, I'd like to install a package onto it (pygobject) which isn't in the Canopy packages, and which needs compiling. Luckily it has a brew script, so I can just run `brew install pygobject`.

My problem is that brew install is not aware of the activated Canopy environment, and simply installs to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Can you tell me what is the right way to combine `brew install` and Canopy? I'd like to have a single Python environment, where I can `brew install` into.

Comment: 2 questions: is this the script you are running with homebrew https://gist.github.com/ches/1094799? And second question: what is the output of "echo $VIRTUAL_ENV"?

Comment: No, I simply want to install pygobject.

Comment: I understand, but my questions still holds. 1. what is the output of "echo $VIRTUAL_ENV"? 2. You are referring to a "brew script". What exactly are you typing to find and run that script?